# How to implement left join on single table using Hibernate framework?

Tags: java, hibernate, struts, hql, hibernate-mapping

How can i implement association mapping and left join in hibernate framework.please help me.....

this is my hibernate mapping class:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.myapp.struts.customer_tree_dao" table="gps_customer_tree">
  <id name="id" column="id">
      <generator class="increment"/>
  </id>
  <property name="customerAccount" column="customer_account"></property>
  <property name="customerName" column="customer_name"></property>
  <property name="parentId" column="parent_id"></property>
  <one-to-many class="com.myapp.struts.customer_tree_dao"></one-to-many>
  </class>
  </hibernate-mapping>
```

this is my bean class:

```
public class customer_tree_dao {

private int id;
private String customerAccount;
private String customerName;
private int parentId;
//Getter and Setter mthods
}
```

this is my action class:

```
Query query_login_account = session.createQuery("from customer_tree_dao c1 left join customer_tree_dao c2 WHERE c2.customerAccount=?");
            query_login_account.setString(0, customerName);
            List Customer_Account = query_login_account.list();
            System.out.println("Left Join Query------------------------------- : "+Customer_Account);
            for (Iterator iterator = Customer_Account.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                customer_tree_dao customer_tree_dao = (customer_tree_dao) iterator.next();
                System.out.println("Customer Login Account-------------------------- : " + customer_tree_dao.getCustomerAccount());
            }
```

but i got Exception:

```
org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource CustomerTree.hbm.xml
```

my database:
[image]

i want this output:

[image]

How can i convert this sql query to HQL.
Please Help me Guys............

Answer (score 0):

When you define one-to-many you have to declare collection (List or Set) in the class to support the mapping and have the related entities instances.

Like this

```
   <set name="subtrees" table="gps_customer_tree"
            inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="parent_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.myapp.struts.customer_tree_dao" />
    </set>
```

And define `Set<customer_tree_dao> subtrees` field in your class
See more here http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-xml-mapping-tutorial/

BWT: Use proper class naving conventions. Class name should start from Capital letter

Comment: i solve the problem. but left join not working.  "from customer_tree_dao c1 left join customer_tree_dao c2 WHERE c2.customerAccount=?"  what can i do?